# Javascript regexp: How to find a string that not ended with a paticular word(not a single letter)?

Tags: javascript, regex, testing, replace, match

```
var s0 = "Hello t0";
var s1 = "Hello b1";
var s2 = "... Hello e2;
var s3 = "xxx Het0llo k3";
var s4 = "er Hello o4";
.....
```

I just want to replace the "x[n]"(at the end) parts excepts "t0" to let's say "ooo";

**Check this:**

```
s0: "Hello t0" => "Hello t0";  // End with "t0", so it won't change;
s1: "Hello t1" => "Hello ooo"; // Changed;
........
```

How can I make it?

---

**Edits**
Thank you all, and sorry for my misleading.

More clearly, some task like this: "Please find all the sentences that not ended with 'mother', and change the last word to 'mother'".

The point is "not just a single character!"!

Comment: Can there be a `t10` (or higher)? Or something like `tx` at the end? (And if so, what should be done with it?)

Answer (score 4):

Isn't this just looking for `/t[^0]$/`? Single character, negate it... Unless I'm missing something, that's your answer.

Comment: You are just think in the right direction!! But not just a single character!! I mean ,yes I am looking for a solution to replace "a tail that not is some word(Maybe not in a 't[n]' format)". More clearly, some task like this: "Please find all the sentences that not ended with 'mother', and replace the last word to 'mother'".

Comment: If it's something like that, just replace all last words with "mother", including the one that is already "mother". The result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
var s0 = "Hello t0";
var s1 = "Hello t1";
var s2 = "... Hello t2";
var s3 = "xxx Het0llo t3";
var s4 = "er Hello t4";

s0.replace(/^(.*?t)[1-9]$/,"$1tt"); // result is: "Hello t0"
s1.replace(/^(.*?t)[1-9]$/,"$1tt"); // result is: "Hello ttt"
s2.replace(/^(.*?t)[1-9]$/,"$1tt"); // result is: "... Hello ttt"
s3.replace(/^(.*?t)[1-9]$/,"$1tt"); // result is: "xxx Het0llo ttt"
s4.replace(/^(.*?t)[1-9]$/,"$1tt"); // result is: "er Hello ttt"
```